# Background audio playback while recording - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-video-player

I am trying to implement a feature such that when a video is being recorded, a selected audio should be playing in the background. I can then use the FFmpeg to overlay the audio and video. I am using the default camera package for recording the video. I would like some guidance in this regard.